# Ngrx: How to simplify the definition of actions?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

Is there any way to simplify the definition of actions so that we don't need to repeat code over and over again?

#### Problem

Working with Ngrx we have to work with actions all the time. In my situation, the most time each action does have a "Do"-Action, a "Success"-Action and a "Failure"-Action. In my situation each of these actions does have the same scope (e.g. "[Authentication]") and the same label (e.g. "Login user").

When I want to create actions for user authentication I would create these as follows:

```
export const loginUser = createAction(
    '[Authentication] DO: Login user',
    props<{
      username: string;
      password: string;
    }
);

export const loginUserSuccess = createAction(
    '[Authentication] SUCCESS: Login user',
    props<{
      token: string;
    }
);

export const loginUserFailure = createAction(
    '[Authentication] FAILURE: Login user',
    props<{
      error: string;
    }
);
```

As you can see there is a lot of repetition:

- three "[Authentication]" for the same scope
- three "Login user" for the same kind of action
- the "DO", "SUCCESS", "FAILURE" parts are the same in all actions

Is there any way to create a factory that simplifies the action creation with less redundant code?

#### My current solution

See my answer to this post.

<s>I created a package `ngrx-simple` with the goal of simplifying ngrx development. It implements a class `SimpleActions` that helps to group actions and reduce code repetition:</s>

https://github.com/julianpoemp/ngrx-simple

---

#### My old solution

(the code in the new package is better)

The only simplification I found so far is creating a class of actions of the same scope and wrap all actions for the same kind of action in an object:

**store.functions.ts**

```
import {createAction, props} from '@ngrx/store';

export function createDoActionType(scope: string, label: string) {
  return `[${scope}] DO: ${label}`;
}

export function createSuccessActionType(scope: string, label: string) {
  return `[${scope}] SUCCESS: ${label}`;
}

export function createErrorAction(scope: string, label: string) {
  return createAction(
    `[${scope}] FAILURE: ${label}`,
    props<ErrorProps>()
  );
}

export interface ErrorProps {
  error: string;
}
```

**authentication.actions.ts**

```
export class AuthenticationActions {
  private static scope = 'Authentication';

    static loginUser = ((scope: string, label: string) => ({
    do: createAction(
      createDoActionType(scope, label),
      props<{
        userEmail: string;
        password: string;
      }>()
    ),
    success: createAction(
      createSuccessActionType(scope, label),
      props<{
        userID: number;
        token: string;
      }>()
    ),
    failure: createErrorAction(scope, label)
  }))(AuthenticationActions.scope, 'Login user');
}
```

I see my solution as workaround only. Although it saves me 10 lines of code, it isn't optimal...

Comment: I'm curious about this situation, first thing I thought like you but I'm still wonder about is there an alternative solution

Comment: I personally like to use redux toolkit combined with ducks pattern for this. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ . So instead of creating a bunch of actions, i create slices with createSlice(). Saves a lot of boilerplate

Comment: https://blog.lacolaco.net/2020/12/angular-using-ngrx-with-redux-toolkit/ here you can see some examples

Comment: @SirOneOfMany thanks for recommending this tool but I would like to keep using Actions

Comment: Have u tried NgRx Component Store ? reduces a LOT of standard NgRx boilerplate

Comment: @PedroBezanilla can you please explain how component store solves my problem?

Comment: Well, I had nightmares at the beginning when I started using NgRx because of that boilerplate you are talking about. Now in some scenarios I use Component store because you reduce the boilerplate substantially. There's some info e.g. https://javascript.plainenglish.io/ngrx-component-store-deep-dive-947c0a5be6dc , but the main Idea is abstracting your component's logic into a ""Store Service"" which has a state, selectors, effects and updaters, all in one file and using few lines.

Comment: I had the same question as you but I recommend creating new actions for every action for better debugging as the project grows. The simplification you have created can be good, I am not sure if it saves much though. Check out this video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY

Comment: I found a way to reduce the code repetition a little more. I hope there'll a better solution...

@AliF50 I don't think my solution makes it more difficult to debug, because I still initialize the actions as before but with less redundant code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ngrx offers a function called `createActionGroup`. It allows to create a set of actions with the same context ("called `source`).

The following example creates a set of actions for a group called "click":

```js
import {createActionGroup} from "@ngrx/store";

export const click = createActionGroup({
  source: 'button/click',
  events: {
      do: props<TestProps>(),
      success: emptyProps(),
      fail: props<TestProps>()
  }
});
```

Now we can dispatch the actions as common:

```js
this.store.dispatch(click.do({test: "ok"});
this.store.dispatch(click.success());
this.store.dispatch(click.fail({test: "ok"});
```

This dispatches actions with following types:

```
[button/click] do
[button/click] success
[button/click] fail
```

In my case there is still need for improvements like a method that creates only the actions "do, success, fail" without the need to set props (no props = emptyProps() automatically). But this is good for now.

Answer (score 3):

My company has open sourced a lib just to handle this as an extension to ngrx.

https://github.com/acandylevey/ngrx-http-tracking

With `createTrackingActions`, 3 actions are created:

- loading -> the request
- loaded
- failure

```
const actionNameSpace = 'Users';

(...)

//                                         Request type     Response Type
//                                                \/          \/   
export const fetchUsers = createTrackingActions<UserRequest, User[]>(
  actionNameSpace,
  'fetchUsers'
);
```

maried with it we have the `createTrackingEffect` function which takes an actions created by `createTrackingActions` and hooks up the 3 underlining actions

```
import { UserApiService } from './user-api.service';
import * as UserActions from './user.actions';

(...)

fetchUsers$ = createTrackingEffect(
    this.actions$,
    UserActions.fetchUsers,
    this.userApi.fetchUsers,
    'Could not load users' // there is a final optional function argument here to allow further function calls after the action is processed.
  );
```

And the reducer is also simplified, as usually only the `loaded` action needs to be handled:

```
const usersReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(UserActions.fetchUsers.loaded, (state, { payload }) =>
    userssAdapter.setAll(payload, { ...state })
  )
);
```

Tracking the results

By default, all actions are tagged with a global tag that can then be easily intercepted a global level, to provide global error handling or a global loading spinner if any actions are waiting on http requests.

`httpTrackingFacade` is also provided by the lib

```
isLoaded$ = this.httpTracker.isLoaded(UserActions.fetchUsers);
 isLoading$ = this.httpTracker.isLoading(UserActions.fetchUsers);

 isGloballyLoading$ = this.httpTrackingFacade.getGlobalLoading();
 globalErrors$ = this.httpTrackingFacade.getGlobalErrors();
```

and to track individual actions There is

Firing the request from a facade

```
 fetchUsers() {
    this.store.dispatch(UserActions.fetchUsers.loading());
    return UserActions.fetchUsers;
  }
```

Tracking it

```
  this.httpTrackingFacade
      .getResolved(this.userFacade.fetchUsers())
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(`The result from the fetch users call was: {result}`);
      });
```

Comment: Interesting solution! But I'm looking for a way to simplify the creation of actions for any purpose. As far as I can see, your solution is applicable only on http requests, am I right? If so, you could (perhaps) find a way to change it so it's applicable on all type of actions.

Comment: it is meant  for http, but it can be used for any action for which there would always be an expected response. For actions without an expected response the standard action is a better fit, it is lean enough I guess